# Code Contracts: How to satisfy 'Ensures Unproven' in property getter?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have the following interface:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(MyObjectContract))]
public interface IMyObject
{
    int CountOfItems { get; }
}
```

The following contract:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IMyObject))]
public abstract class MyObjectContract
{
    int IMyObject.CountOfItems
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The following implementation:

```
public class MyObject : IMyObject
{
    private IEnumerable someEnumerable .... 

    public int CountOfItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this.someEnumerable.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting a warning saying `ensures unproven: Contract.Result<int>() > 0`

How am I supposed to prove that count is greater than zero? I don't want to throw an exception in a getter, what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: It cannot prove that the enumerable is going to return > 0. But I'm not sure how you'd enforce it. Also, I'd change `someEnumerable` into a list or an array otherwise it'll be iterated fully each time someone calls `CountOfItems`.

Comment: Your code implies an object invariant that `someEnumerable.Count()` will always be greater than zero. Your first step to satisfying the property contract should be to make that object invariant explicit in your code. The details of how to satisfy that invariant depend on the details of how your code already assures that the invariant is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you cannot statically prove that `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` returns a value greater than 0 due to limitations of the Base Class Library (.NET Framework) and the static checker. However, you can indicate to the static checker that you *assume* that fact to be true. This is the way you solve all such contract problems with the Base Class Libraries, or statements that the static checker cannot prove.

```
public int CountOfItems
{
    get
    {
        int count = this.someEnumerable.Count();
        Contract.Assume(count > 0);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't prove this in static.
`Enumerable.Count<TSource>` extension method doesn't define any contract about its return value (e.g., what this method should return for the endless sequence?).

So, CC stais checker warns you about this.

Comment: But surely it want me to prove `CountOfItems`, not `Enumerable.Count`?  The contract is for the behaviour of my object, not the internal implementation.. unless I've misunderstood something here..

Comment: The more I think about this answer, the more I think it's wrong. How, in the most general case, do you prove an ensures in a property getter? Apologies if I have misunderstood what you mean..

Comment: @MalcomTucker: Static checker tries to prove contract by analyzing code. Your contract declares that `IMyObject.CountOfItems` will always be greater, than zero. OK, says static checker, let's look into code. Aha, there's call to `Enumerable.Count`. Does `Enumerable.Count` guarantee, that it always return a value, greater that zero? No, it doesn't. Сonsequence: there's no way to prove statically this contract. The only thing you can do here, is an assumption (see `Contract.Assume`), that `someEnumerable.Count > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your code is correct. It works, and you are merely trying to get the code contracts system to recognize that fact.

This means specifically that calling `CountOfItems` on an instance of `MyObject` will always return a value greater than zero. It will not throw an exception, and it will not return a value of zero or less.

This means that `someEnumerable` will be assigned to some object, and  `someEnumerable.Count()` will always return a value greater than zero for whatever object is referenced. These facts will be true at all times (since there is no restriction on when `CountOfItems` may be called.

This implies that there is an object invariant (whether it's spelled-out explicitly in the code or not) for `MyObject` which includes those facts. And since your code is correct (by assumption), the implementation of `MyObject` guarantees that `someEnumerable` is assigned and its count is greater than zero at all times.

Thus, in order to satisfy the contract on `CountOfItems`, the contracts system needs to be made aware of these invariants and how they are ensured.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I follow where you're going with this. On a related note - is it even necessary or desirable to *prove* everything Code Contracts warns you about? If I can't prove this invariant, but because of the structure of the code and the way it is consumed the ensures is actually true, is that sufficient?

Comment: It would certainly be awesome if we could formally prove our code is correct. I don't actually have access to the static checker, so I don't know what it can do, but from what I have heard from others, we are not yet at the place where everything can be proven in this manner. As long as you can prove to yourself that it is correct, then an assertion of the fact may be all you need for the contracts. If, however, the invariant depends on code outside of this module ("the way it is consumed"), then I would not make the assertion. Rather, I would go ahead and throw an exception or something.

Answer (score 0):

It appears adding a `ContractInvariant` method to the implementation resolves the warning.

Comment: An example of how this works would get my up-vote at least.